# I want to have a check box highlight when a user selects it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have build a template in HTML, using CSS and part of java. I have added check boxes example quesiton1, do you have trouble lifting above your arm> Yes or no with 2 check boxes and or radio buttons. I want to be able to highlight the box the user selects I've been working on this trying to use this script but its not working.

```js
function checkYellow() {
  var ins = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i=0; i<ins.length; i++) {
    if (ins[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
      if ( ins[i].checked == true)
        ins[i].style.backgroundColor="yellow";
      else
        ins[i].style.backgroundColor="white";
    }
  }
}
```

I'm still learning HTML, CSS, and javascript. Thanks for any help. I copied this from a previous form, and inserted it into mine but Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS alone - no scripting required!

Given something like this:

```
<div class="checkbox-holder">
  <input type="checkbox" id="the-box"/></input>
  <label class="checkbox-label" for="the-box">A checkbox!</label>
</div>
```

You can use CSS like this to highlight the label:

```
.checkbox-label {
  border: 10px;
  background: gray;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-label {
  background: yellow;
}
```

The key part here is how we select the labels to turn yellow:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-label
```

This selects anything with the class `checkbox-label` that comes immediately after an `input` tag, whose type is `checkbox`, and which is also marked as `checked`.

CSS selectors are very useful. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) - the Mozilla docs go into detail about all the options you have.

Comment: Here is my actual code I'm using so where would I place the CSS at in side here- I'm still trying to learn this                             <TD>&nbsp;<INPUT id=CheckBox1 type=checkbox name=CheckBox1 ex_ctrlid="CheckBox1" ex_ctrltype="CheckBox"></INPUT></INPUT>&nbsp;Yes 
<TD>&nbsp;<INPUT id=CheckBox3 type=checkbox name=CheckBox3 ex_ctrlid="CheckBox3" ex_ctrltype="CheckBox"></INPUT>&nbsp; Yes</TD></TD></TR>